# find the smallest number that is bigger than a defined parameter number

Tags: python

i want to find number in list that is the closest to my number but bigger then him.

for example:

```
num = 20
li = [19,23,24,1,2]
```

i want to get 23.

i tried doing this:

```
hour = min(dfHour, key=lambda x:(x-localtime[3])>0)
```

but it return just the closest even if it is not bigger from my number

another question is if i have another 23 in the list, how can i return them both(their indexes is quite good enough)

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use filter:

```
print min(filter(lambda x: x > num,li))
23
```

If you have duplicate values:

```
num = 20
li = [19,23,24,23,1,2]
li_sort = sorted(x for x in li if x > num)
print [x for x in li_sort  if x == li_sort[0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
num = 20

li = [19,23,24,1,2]
higher = []

for number in li:
    if number > num:
        higher.append(number)

if higher:
    lowest = sorted(higher)[0]

print(lowest)
```

You can easily convert to a function:

```
def closest(num, li):
    higher = []

    for number in li:
        if number > num:
            higher.append(number)

    if higher:
        lowest = sorted(higher)[0]

        return lowest
    else:
        return "Error"
```